# Double/Triple number of vertices on a solid object (somewhat rectangular)

Tags: vertices

I have somewhat a very non-intricate solid mesh of a recangular looking object (cannot share) that currently only has 88 vertices. What's a good way to increase number of vertices to 2x/3x the current value? I am using this mesh for an upstream deep learning algorithm and with current number of vertices I get this error:

```
n_points:  100
points.shape:  torch.Size([128, 88, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/megapose/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/megapose/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/scripts/run_inference_on_example.py", line 249, in <module>
    run_inference(example_dir, args.model)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/scripts/run_inference_on_example.py", line 157, in run_inference
    output, _ = pose_estimator.run_inference_pipeline(
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/megapose/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/inference/pose_estimator.py", line 576, in run_inference_pipeline
    data_TCO_coarse, coarse_extra_data = self.forward_coarse_model(
  File "/home/mona/anaconda3/envs/megapose/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/inference/pose_estimator.py", line 413, in forward_coarse_model
    out_ = coarse_model.forward_coarse(
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/models/pose_rigid.py", line 682, in forward_coarse
    images_crop, K_crop, boxes_rend, boxes_crop = self.crop_inputs(
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/models/pose_rigid.py", line 217, in crop_inputs
    points = meshes.sample_points(100, deterministic=True)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/lib3d/rigid_mesh_database.py", line 169, in sample_points
    return sample_points(self.points, n_points, deterministic=deterministic)
  File "/home/mona/megapose6d/src/megapose/lib3d/mesh_ops.py", line 86, in sample_points
    point_ids = np_random.choice(points.shape[1], size=n_points, replace=False)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 984, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

Comment: The simplest solution seems subdivision. You can add a subdivision modifier, make sure it is in the **simple** mode, and then you can apply it. If this for some reason doesn't work, can you produce a simple example mesh with similar topological properties?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you followed your instructions and it worked. Would you please be able to add this as answer? It was very helpful